# How to delete lower case from a list and reverse it

Tags: python, list, reverse, lowercase

The aim is trying to reverse the message, delete all the strings that starts with lower case letter and at the end make everything lower case.

This is my code:

```
msg = input('code: ')
msg = msg.split()
msg = list(reversed(msg))
for i in msg:
  if i[0] == i[0].lower:
    del msg[i]
msg = ' '.join(msg)
msg = msg.lower()
print(msg)
```

Here is one example

```
BaSe fOO ThE AttAcK
```

Then it will turn into

```
attack the base
```

Thank you guys so much!!!!!!!!! so i went back and edited my code:

```
new_msg = []
msg = input('code: ')
msg = msg.split()
msg = list(reversed(msg))
for word in msg:
  if not word[0].islower():
    new_msg.append(word.lower())
new_msg = ' '.join(new_msg)
print("says:",new_msg)
```

and i went back to mark it but it said you can't have punctuation! yeah, i think i need help again, how do i get rid of them?

Comment: You can elegantly keep only certain items in a list using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_msg = []
msg = msg.split()
for word in msg: #For every word in the string
    if not word[0].islower(): #if it starts with anything other than lowercase
        new_msg.append(word.lower()) #add to new list
new_msg = ' '.join(new_msg[::-1]) #Reverse order of list and make into string
```

Comment: This code _retains_ strings that start with a lower case letter; The OP requires _removal_ of strings that begin with a lower case letter. That can be fixed by changing to `if not word[0].islower()`. Also this code does not convert retained strings to lower case. Nor does it produce a string - it produces a list.

Comment: Fixed. And it actually produced an iterator, not a string (so, even worse!)

Comment: That's slightly better, but still wrong. What if a word starts with a digit, punctuation, or other non-letter character? The OP requests to "delete all the strings that starts with lower case letter", e.g. `1abcd` should be retained, but your code would delete it. `if not word[0].islower():` is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Fair enough! Updated (again :) )

Answer (score 2):

Here's why your code doesn't *work*, at least:

```
>>> i = 'fOO'

>>> i[0] == i[0].lower     # huh?
False

>>> i[0].lower             # oh!
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x00249F40>

>>> i[0].lower()           # we forgot to *call* it
'f'

>>> i[0] == i[0].lower()   # perfect!
True
```

You're comparing a string to a method object -- that's why the condition is never hit.

If you fix this error, it still won't work; you're deleting `msg['fOO']` which doesn't make any sense! Try using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index along with the strings in the list.

(And then it *still* won't work. Can you find out why?)

Answer (score 1):

This looks a little intimidating, but I'll explain it.

```
s = "BaSe fOO ThE AttAcK"
print ' '.join(reversed([word.lower() for word in s.split(' ') if not word[0].islower()]))
```

What I'm doing here is splitting s at a single space `' '`, which then creates a list of anything not a single `' '`. Then I iterate through the list of "words" and convert each word to lower using the  built-in lower method only if the first character of the word (which we get by calling the 0th index) is not lower. Lastly we join the list we created using the join method.

Edit: I forgot to reverse the list.

Comment: This is the only correct alternative implementation so far. FWIW, it could be _slightly_ more efficient if the conversion to lower case was performed on the joined string, rather than in the list comprehension.

Comment: Yeah it would be more efficient that way, nice catch.

Answer (score -1):

```
" ".join([word.lower() for word in reversed(msg.split()) if not word[0].islower()])
```

Comment: What if one of the words starts with a digit or punctuation character? Contrary to the OP's requirement, this code will remove it.

Answer (score -1):

```
string = raw_input().split()                                                     
string2 = []                                                                     
for i in range(len(string)):                                                     
    if not string[i].[0].islower():                  
        string2.insert(0,string[i].lower())                                              
print ' '.join(string2)
```

Comment: Use `islower()` rather than ASCII values. The former will work properly with non-ASCII characters. Besides, words beginning with lowercase `z` will not be removed as required - you probably meant `<= 122`.

Comment: Try `string[i][0].islower()` rather than `string[i].[0].islower()`

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you don't delete any element in list/Dict iteration in any case.
If you do, it will be wrong.

Like that:

```
sMsg="BaSe fOO The AttAck"
lstMsg=sMsg.split(" ")
for i in xrange(len(lstMsg)):
    if lstMsg[i][0].islower():
        del lstMsg[i]
```